# Badge reason error

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to show badges on our system, badges are rewards/achievement to users. They show on their profile, the thing that works is the image/badge shows, but the badge reason doesn't.

I tried to do it like this

```
<?
    $badgesql = mysql_query("select * from usr_badge where user = '$user'");
    $user2 = mysql_query("select * from usr_users where username = '$user'");
    $usr2 = mysql_fetch_array($user2);
    $vipsql = mysql_query("select * from usr_vip where userid = '$usr2[id]'");
    $vipcheck = mysql_num_rows($vipsql);
    $badgecheck = mysql_num_rows($badgesql);
    $checkit = $badgecheck + $vipcheck;
    if($checkit==0)
    echo("This user does not have any badges");
    else
    if($badgecheck!=0)
    {
    while($badge = mysql_fetch_array($badgesql))
    {
    echo('<a onclick="TINY.box.show({html:'Reason: '.$badge[reason].',animate:false,close:false,mask:false,boxid:'success',autohide:2,top:-14,left:-17})"><img src="'.$badge[badge].'" </a>');
    }
    }
    //Display VIP Badges
    if($vipcheck!=0)
    {
    $vipbadge = mysql_fetch_array($vipsql);
    $vip1 = mysql_query("select * from usr_vipdb where id = '$vipbadge[vipid]'");
    $vip2 = mysql_fetch_array($vip1);
        echo('<img src="'.$vip2[url].'" alt="This user is a VIP!" />');
    }
    ?>
```

but that code above doesn't work. It gives me an error when I try to view the page "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/********/public_html/memb.php on line 167"

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm also guessing your open and close quotes don't line up. Simply judging by the syntax highlighting in your code block

Comment: Also found an open `img` tag which I just corrected in my answer

Comment: Hi, I've just reverted an edit to this post - in general once a question has been asked it should only be tweaked, so that the corresponding answers still make sense. If you have a substantially different question to ask, open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

That long line starting with `echo` is probably at fault -- the syntax highlighting *here* is broken with it, showing that you've probably mis-matched the quotes or something similar. (Break it apart. Make each small segment on its own line. You won't miss the mistake then.)

Here's your current code broken as I believe the interpreter will parse it:

```
echo('<a onclick="TINY.box.show({html:'
Reason: '.$badge[reason].'
,animate:false,close:false,mask:false,boxid:
'success'
,autohide:2,top:-14,left:-17})
"><img src="
'.$badge[badge].'
" </a>');
```

Note the line starting with the bare word `Reason:`. Since that's not the error you got, perhaps I guessed incorrectly, but there's no doubt that your current code is too messy.

I hope you are sanitizing your inputs (`$user`, `$usr2[id]`) and stored data (`$badge[reason]`) in code that is not shown here to protect against [cross-site scripting vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @HilraJannar: it isn't intended as a fix. It is simply intended to point out that your string is supremely complicated. Kyle's got the end solution in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (fixed open/close quotes... i think)

```
<?
    $badgesql = mysql_query("select * from usr_badge where user = '$user'");
    $user2 = mysql_query("select * from usr_users where username = '$user'");
    $usr2 = mysql_fetch_array($user2);
    $vipsql = mysql_query("select * from usr_vip where userid = '$usr2[id]'");
    $vipcheck = mysql_num_rows($vipsql);
    $badgecheck = mysql_num_rows($badgesql);
    $checkit = $badgecheck + $vipcheck;
    if($checkit==0) {
        echo("This user does not have any badges");

    } else {
        if($badgecheck!=0)
        {
            while($badge = mysql_fetch_array($badgesql))
            {
                echo('<a onclick="TINY.box.show({html: "Reason: '.$badge[reason].'",animate:false,close:false,mask:false,boxid:"success",autohide:2,top:-14,left:-17})"><img src="'.$badge[badge].'" /></a>');
            }
        }
        //Display VIP Badges
        if($vipcheck!=0)
        {
            $vipbadge = mysql_fetch_array($vipsql);
            $vip1 = mysql_query("select * from usr_vipdb where id = '$vipbadge[vipid]'");
            $vip2 = mysql_fetch_array($vip1);
            echo('<img src="'.$vip2[url].'" alt="This user is a VIP!" />');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: At least the highlighting here is fixed. :)

Comment: @sarnold I haven't done PHP in a while... would this be a bad place for a heredoc? Or not really?

Comment: I tried this and the error is gone, can view the badge but when I click on the image to pop-up the reason, it just doesn't.

Comment: @Kyle, I think it is a bit overkill for a here-doc, but breaking it onto three or four lines wouldn't hurt anything. :)

Comment: @HilraJannar Press F12 (IE) or CTRL + SHIFT + J (Firefox, Chrome) and check your Javascript Developer Console for errors, and open up another question.

Comment: Done. Uncaught ReferenceError: anylinkcssmenu is not defined memb.php:272
14event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined memb.php:272
4event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.

Comment: @HilraJannar Ok, Accept one of these answers by clicking the green check to the left of the one that fixed your problem, then open a new question because your new problem is unrelated to your original question